# Problems opening local php page

Tags: php, network-programming, localhost, local

i just instaled xampp and  I'm trying to run php page. But i have a problem:

> This Page Cannot Be Displayed
>
> Based on your organization's security policies, this web site ( http://localhost/sajt/index.php ) has been blocked because it has been determined to be a security threat to your computer or the organization's network. Access could also be blocked because this request came from an unrecognized or unauthorized machine.
>
> If you have questions, please contact your organization's network administrator and provide the codes shown below.
>
> Date: Fri, 11 Nov 2016 00:45:12 CET
>   Username: 
>   Source IP: 147.91.36.--
>   URL: GET http://localhost/sajt/index.php
>   Category: LocalHost
>   Reason: BLOCK-PROTOCOL
>   Notification: POLICY

Does anyone knows what to do? How to unblock local pages?  Does anyone have similar problem?

Comment: Firewall or company policy - if the first, turn off your firewall for localhost, if second, talk to company IT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you run xammp on a personal computer or on a computer provided by your employer?

"Based on your organization's security policies" COULD indicate that your company setup an extra layer of security on your system.

EDIT: This could also mean a firewall is blocking the website from being visited.

Comment: I use on my personal computer but connection goes through proxy

Comment: Have you tried disabling that proxy to see what it does?

Comment: Oh it works when i turned it off... And theres option also "Dont use proxy for local addresses" so i can use it with proxy enabled! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Glad you where able to get it to work, good luck on the rest :)